# Part of my script in JavaScript is not running in the browser unless commented out

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening family. So I'm trying to write a JS script which does two things, firstly it alerts the users when the top button is clicked (*button), and secondly it's suppose to be able to download a file that the users uploads to the browser (*download) (nothing to do with a server so far).
The problem I encounter is that if the second part is commented out, the *button part works fine, but when it is not nothing works.
Help would be much appreciated.
JS

```
 // HOME BUTTON
document.querySelector("#home").addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert("YESSIR!!!");
});

const up-file= document.querySelector("#file");
const dl-link= document.querySelector("#dl-link");
let objectURL;
// DOWNLOAD
up-file.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
    if(objectURL){
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    }
    const file= this.files[0];
    objectURL= URL.createObjectURL(file);
    dl-link.href= objectURL;
    dl-link.click();
});
```

HTML

```
<button id= "home">HOME</button>
<!-- DL-->
<label>Upload</label>
<input type= "file" id= "file"/>
<a id= "dl-link" download></a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Always check the console for errors! Javascript variable names can't contain a `-` character, so your code has syntax errors and won't run when you include the lines with `const up-file` and `const dl-link`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming of your const variables is wrong, replace this lines with 
`const up_file = document.querySelector("#file");` 
`const dl_link = document.querySelector("#dl-link");`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names in javaScript cannot contain dashes "-", that's what's causing a syntax error. But you have other issues in the code to be solved, so always check the console under developer tools in the web browser you're using to know what errors are being thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.